# How can I increase the capacity of a 3.7V lithium polymer battery?

Tags: batteries, lipo

I have a Raspberry Pi Pico W that I want to power using a battery.  All the 3.7V lithium polymer batteries I can find are up to around 5000mAh which doesn't power the Pico for too long. Ideally I want the battery to last about a month.

Is there a way to link multiple2 batteries to act as one larger capacity battery?

Comment: Are there times the pico could be put into a sleep mode?

Comment: Welcome! Yes you can, but at one month runtime, you should look for alternatives such as solar, deep sleep and other power saving measures.

Comment: You can connect more pieces of same LiPo parallel. Just be careful when you make a parallel connection they have the same voltage. Discharge one with higher Vbatt to the one with smaller Vbatt via power resistor so Vbatt stays equal.